# actualizar status strip desde formulario hijo a formulario padre MDI

Tags: c#

Estimados amigos.

Tengo un formulario padre MDI con varias opciones de menu, en el cual tengo un control status Strip, y pongo como ejemplo al abrir un formulario de mi ficha de cientes y al hacer una consulta deseo mostrar en mi barra de estado del formulario MDI "Ejecutando consulta..." desde mi formulario hijo Clientes.cs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
mi codigo en form MDI al seleccionar la opcion Clientes

```
    private void mnuConsultasClientes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmClientes frm = this.MdiChildren.OfType<frmClientes>().Where(x => x.Name == "frmClientes").FirstOrDefault();
        if (frm == null)
        {
            sbEstado.Text = "Abriendo formulario Clientes..";
            frmClientes frmClientes = new frmClientes();
            frmClientes.MdiParent = this;
            frmClientes.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            frmClientes.Show();
            sbEstado.Text = "Listo";
        }
        else
        {
            frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }
```

Al hacer una consulta de clientes por ejemplos todos los que empiezan por VAS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo en boton Consultar.

```
    private void tsBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        errorProvider1.Clear();
        if (txtBusqueda.Text.ToString().Trim()==String.Empty)
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtBusqueda, "Ingrese un criterio de busqueda...");
            return;
        }

        //MessageBox.Show(cboBuscarPor.SelectedIndex.ToString());

        switch (cboBuscarPor.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                sb.Append(" AND CLI.CLI_NOMBRE LIKE '" + txtBusqueda.Text.ToString().Trim() + "%'");
                break;
            case 1:
                sb.Append(" AND CLI.CLI_RUC LIKE '" + txtBusqueda.Text.ToString().Trim() + "%'");
                break;
        }

        //dgvLista.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgvLista.DataSource = nCliente.GetListClientes(sb.ToString());

    }
```

Gracias por su amable ayuda.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el ID del control `ToolStripStatusLabel` y del `StatusStrip` de tu formulario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una manera en como puedes hacerlo es exponiendo una variable estatica con la instancia del formulario, en el formulario principal. A esta variariable sera para asignarle el texto a `sbEstado`:

```
public class MainForm : Form
{
   public static String Status {
     set { 
           instance.sbEstado.Text = value;
     }
   }

   private static MainForm instance;
   public MainForm()
   {
       //..
       instance = this;
   }
  //...
}
```

Entonces para utilizarlo en otro formulario solo tendrias que asignar el valor a la variable estatica del formulario:

```
private void tsBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       MainForm.Status = "Buscando...";

       //...
       //...
       dgvLista.DataSource = nCliente.GetListClientes(sb.ToString());
       MainForm.Status = "Listo";

}
```

Una de las limitantes que tiene esta solucion es que no puedes asignar el estado desde otro hilo porque solo se puede modificar un control desde el hilo de la vista.

Comment: Gracias amigo funciono a la perfeccion.

Answer (score 0):

Cuatro cosas a tener en cuenta :

1.- Asegurate que el formulario principal tenga la propiedad IsMdiContainer activa.

2.- Desde tu formulario hijo, puedes referenciar al padre mediante MdiParent.

3.- Asegurate que al instanciar al hijo le asignes el MdiParent (Ya lo estas haciendo)

4.- Asegurate que el ámbito del control que desees cambiar no esté protejido y te permita hacer el cambio desde el hijo. ( Propiedad Modifiers del control lblMensaje debe ser Public)

Ahora si :

```
frmPadre f = (frmPadre)this.MdiParent;
f.lblMensaje.Texto = "Listo!.";
```

Espero te sea de utilidad,